# $E[|T\cap S|^2]$ for random sets $S$, $T$ with fixed number of member $|S|=|T|=d$

Tags: combinatorics, stochastic-calculus

Let two sets $T,S\subset\{1,\dots, p\}$ be given. Both sets have $d<p$ elements, i.e. $|S|=|T|=d$

Find $E[|T\cap S|^2]$ for random sets $S$, $T$, i.e. if $\mathcal{S}$ is the set over all those sets, find

$$\frac{1}{|\mathcal{S}|^2}\sum_{S,T\in \mathcal{S}}|S\cap T|^2$$

Is this simply
$$\sum_{k=0}^p \frac{\binom{d}{k}\binom{d}{d-k}}{d!}k^2=\frac{4^{d-1}d\Gamma\left(d-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi}\left(\left(d-1\right)!\right)^2}$$
Probably this also must be dependent of $p$, doesn't it?

Comment: If $(S,T)$ has uniform distribution over $\mathcal S^2$ then the first formula is correct. I do not understand the second. I miss the division by $|\mathcal S^2|=\binom{p}{d}^2$ there.

Comment: Yes, uniform distribution over $\mathcal{S}$, the second formula is wrong, I just wanted to share my thoughts

Comment: @Vera do you think there is just $\binom{p}{d}^{-2}$ missing?

Comment: How about $\sum_{k=0}^p \frac{\binom{d}{k}\binom{p}{d-k}}{p!}k^2$

Comment: Or $\sum_{k=0}^p \frac{\binom{d}{k}\binom{p-d}{d-k}}{\binom{p}{d}}k^2$ this seems logical now

Comment: I think that the term for $k$ must be something like $\frac12\binom{p}{k}\binom{p-k}{d-k}\binom{p-d}{d-k}k^2$. Here factor $\frac12$ to neutralize double counting (the order of $(S,T)$ does not matter).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @Vera. I though we can fix one set, say $S$ and now calculate $P(|S\cap T|=k)$ which is equal over all fixed sets $S$ because of symmetry reasons. Now I have $\binom{d}{k}$ possibilities to match $T$ with $S$; $\binom{p}{d-k}$ possibilities not to match divided by $\binom{p}{d}$ sets with cardinality $d$. Is there an error?

Comment: My approach is first selecting $k$ out of $p$ to be set $S\cap T$. Then selecting $d-k$ out of the remaining $p-k$ for determining $S$ as upperset of $S\cap T$. Then again selecting $d-k$ out the $p-d$ elements that are not yet in $S$ for determining $T$ as upperset of $S\cap T$. I think I was wrong by adding factor $\frac12$ because order does matter. It is more difficult to find mistakes of someone else :-). Maybe it is an idea to test both approaches on small numbers and see if anything goes wrong. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vera, I think both ways should work, and the results are probably equal

Comment: I checked with wolfram alpha, both results coincide so the result should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to mention an alternative.

For $i=1,\dots,p$ define random variable $X_i$ as taking value $1$ if $i\in S\cap T$ and taking value $0$ otherwise.

Then:$$|S\cap T|^2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^pX_i\right)^2=\sum_{i=1}^p\sum_{j=1}^pX_iX_j$$Using symmetry we then find that:$$\mathbb E|S\cap T|^2=p\mathbb EX_1^2+p(p-1)\mathbb EX_1X_2=p\Pr(1\in S\cap T)+p(p-1)\Pr(1,2\in S\cap T)$$

Work this out...